# Self referencing table where reference is NOT NULL

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, self-referencing-table

Is it possible to have a self-referencing entity where the self-reference ID is NOT NULL?  See my sample entity where `parent.parent_id` is configured with `nullable=false`.  When I flush, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'parent_id' cannot be null (0) class: Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException
```

A trigger would work, however, I would rather not manually add a trigger.  Could Doctrine be configured to generate a trigger?  Maybe a lifecycle callback can be used?

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ParentClass
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="parent")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ParentClass
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ParentClass", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $child;

    /**
     * @var ParentClass
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ParentClass", inversedBy="child")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->child = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add child.
     *
     * @param ParentClass $child
     *
     * @return ParentClass
     */
    public function addChild(ParentClass $child)
    {
        $this->child[] = $child;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child.
     *
     * @param ParentClass $child
     *
     * @return boolean TRUE if this collection contained the specified element, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function removeChild(ParentClass $child)
    {
        return $this->child->removeElement($child);
    }

    /**
     * Get child.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChild()
    {
        return $this->child;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent.
     *
     * @param ParentClass $parent
     *
     * @return ParentClass
     */
    public function setParent(ParentClass $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent.
     *
     * @return ParentClass
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the first element that you will save in your table, you can put the parent as the element it self and in this case you avoid the null value.

Comment: @KubiRoazhon  How can MySQL save the record in the first place?  Unless Doctrine will disable foreign constraints automatically when saving the first record which it appears not to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it will work

```
public function addParent(ParentClass $parent)
{
    $this->parent[] = $parent;
    $parent->setParent($this);
    return $this;
}

public function removeParent(ParentClass $parent)
{
    $this->parent->removeElement($parent);
}

public function setParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

public function addParent(ParentClass $parent)
{
    $this->parent[] = $parent;
    $parent->setParent($this);
    return $this;
}

public function removeParent(ParentClass $parent)
{
    $this->parent->removeElement($parent);
}

public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}
```